# xml data to multiple frames in flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am making a dynamic quiz in flash. I can call the xml nodes into the text fields but I need the data to be on the next frame as well. For that I made two array first global and the other in a function. But I don't know how to bring data of the array inside the function to the outside array. When I trace the data is shows result inside function but it does not show outside the function.
My code is:

```
var array:Array = new Array  ;
var t:TextField;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("xml-file.xml"));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    ParsePass(xmlData);

}

function ParsePass(passInput:XML):void
{

    var temp = new Array  ;
    for (var i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        temp[i] = xmlData.children()[i];
        t.text = temp[0]

        MovieClip(root).array = temp;
trace(array);
        //trace(temp[i]);
    }
}
```

Although I found the same hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758550/how-to-load-xml-data-and-present-it-across-multiple-frames-in-as3)
but I could not understand properly.

Thanks!

Comment: @IvanH can you answer please!

Comment: I came to your question only as reviewer of suggested edits. I am not experienced in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... `array` not equals `MovieClip(root).array`.

Change this line

```
MovieClip(root).array = temp;
```

to

```
array = temp;
```

Please try it.